# FOC current ripples with angle dependencies

Tags: control-engineering, motors

I implemented the FOC (Field Oriented Control) algorithm to control a BLDC motor at low speed. A phenomena I observed is, that at different electrical angles, the torque producing current breaks down and the field producing current increases (mostly around +-90°). I use a simple PI controller and no cross coupling compensation. If I keep this angle, the field producing current stays then constant at a nonzero value. Does anyone know, what could producing this phenomena? Maybe someone of you already implemented a FOC algorithm for a BLDC motor and also noticed this problem.

Comment: It could help to have more information, such as: 1) Your test setup - I guess you are rotating at slow speed and applying some external torque? 2) A graph of how the currents and rotor position behave.